# How to check email address exists or not in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I want check to email address exist.
In Codeigniter mail sent to all email address that's may be exist or not exist.
Why Codeigniter email library sent mail method return always true.

Comment: Same as @Joerg's answer. The Codeigniter mail method returns if it sending succeed or not. Not delivered or not. By the way, if you try and error whether the address exists or not, you would probably be blocked by the server (I guess). And It won't have returning messages sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no worldwide registration system for emails, nobody knows if an address exists or not. So, you have to do a try and error, means: send a mail to the address and catch the returning delivery error in the mail account which you are using for sending.

The Codeigniter mail library gives a true back, because sending the mail was successful.It doesn't and can't catch delivery errors.